# Generalized integration by parts

Tags: real-analysis, integration, vector-analysis

It is easy to see from Green's identity that if $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ and $u\in C^\infty(\Omega)$ then $$\int_\Omega u\nabla^2 \varphi \:dV=\int_\Omega \varphi\nabla^2 u\:dV$$

But how would one generalize this result for higher order derivatives? That is, consider $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ and $u\in C^{|\alpha|}(\Omega)$ for a multi index $\alpha$ how does one show that $$\int u\partial^\alpha \varphi \:dx=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int \varphi \partial^\alpha u\:dx$$
I think that one just needs to integrate by parts $|\alpha|$ times but i'm having some troubles proving that $$\left[u\int\partial^\alpha \varphi\right]_\Omega=0$$ I believe that it all follows from $\varphi$ having being compactly supported by $\Omega$ but i can't formly argue it.

Thank you for time.

Comment: Hint: $\int\int \partial_x \phi(x,y) dx\;dy = \int [\int \partial_x \phi(x,y)dx]dy$

Comment: It suffices to prove $\int_{\Omega}u\partial_i\phi\,dx=-\int_{\Omega}(\partial_iu)\phi\,dx$, because your general statement follows from this by induction. In order to prove this statement, it suffices to prove that $\int_{\Omega}\partial_i(u\phi)\,dx=0$, or even more simply that for any $f\in C^1_c(\Omega)$, we have $\int_{\Omega}\partial_if\,dx=0$. To prove this, use Fubini to integrate over $x^i$ first, and then use FTC to evaluate the integral, and compact support to claim it is actually 0.